# within changed the default parameter in dart

Tags: dart

as code below , the default type of DB is null instead of 10; is it a bug

```
class DA{
  int age;
  int type;
  DA(this.age,[this.type=10]);
}
mixin C {
  String name;
}

class DB extends DA with C{
  DB(int age):super(age);
}
void main(){
  var a=DB(11);
  print(a.type);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug as shown in this Dart issues report: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/31767

Another example with and without mixins

```
class DA{
  int age;
  int type;
  DA(this.age,[this.type=10]);
}

mixin C {
  String name;
}

class DB extends DA {
  DB(int age):super(age);
}

class DC extends DA with C{
  DC(int age):super(age);
}

void main(){
  var a = DA(11); 
  var b = DB(11);
  var c = DC(11);
  print("A: ${a.type}"); // A: 10  (base class ok)
  print("B: ${b.type}"); // B: 10   (inherited class ok)
  print("C: ${c.type}"); // C: null  (inherited with mixin not ok)
}
```